# Arranging a list to ouput equidistant points

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, function, range

I want to write a code that prints the first and last number within a list as well as 5 other points. The points have to be equidistant from each other as well. So the numbers outputted would be `25, 19, 29, 16, 20`.

```
list_ = [25, 23, 14, 22, 19, 13, 12, 10, 28, 29, 11, 15, 18, 27, 16, 21, 20, 17, 24, 26]
```

Comment: It's confusing to see your sample output: [25, 19, 29, 16, 20].  Can you show us what's been tried and where you got questions?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking for？

```py
>>> size = len(lst)
>>> size // 5     # five elements starting with first one.
4
>>> 
>>> for i in range(0, size, size//5):
    print(lst[i])

    
25
19
28
18
20
```